# PayPal決済ページのエラー：データが入力文字セットまたはデフォルトのエンコーディングに一致しません。

Tags: paypal

PayPalボタンをクリックすると、下記のエラーが表示されます。

データが入力文字セットまたはデフォルトのエンコーディングに一致しません。詳細情報については、マーチャントにお問い合わせください。
Data does not match input character set or default encoding. For more information, please contact the merchant.
正規期間が無効です。購読に関するA3、P3、及びT3パラメータに有効な値を指定する必要があります。
Invalid Regular period. You must specify valid values for the A3, P3 and T3 parameters for a subscription.
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

基本的にこのエラーは、マーチャントのウェブサイトのエンコーディングがアカウント上のエンコーディングと違う場合は発生します。

下記の手順でアカウントのエンコーディング設定を確認できます。
①   www.paypal.comでログインし、イアカウント->個人設定->販売ツール　で、「PayPalボタンの言語コード化」をクリックする
または、下記URLにアクセスする：
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/customerprofileweb?cmd=_profile-language-encoding
②   詳細オプション」ボタンをクリックする。
次の画面で表示されているエンコーディングはマーチャントのウェブサイトのエンコーディングと一致しなければなりません。

マーチャントのウェブサイトのエンコーディングはUTF-8が圧倒的に多いので、
その画面でUTF-8を選択し、保存してから、ボタンの遷移を再確認してみたください。

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask